# admob fillrate = 0

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

i'm using admob for an app i just launched the other day, at first there were no downloads, but with a campaign i'm using now, i've gotten 140 requests yesterday and as of now, 44 and counting... but still, on the old admob website, it says that it isn't active because it has not yet received any ad request.

I have another app in the admob list, and it is showing on the old website as a green light.

I don't think there is anything wrong with my code, otherwise there wouldn't be any requests, am i right?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Also: i couldn't find any contact to write to..

**EDIT**

P.S. test ads are showing on my smartphone and on the emulator..

**EDIT**

This is what is being shown to me of today:

```
Request 299
Impressions 0
Fill Rate 0%
CTR -
....
```

Comment: This is the only info i have.. i've searched around but there was nothing useful

Comment: i also checked the app unit id and it is the right one..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What should I do? Since the code is right,  requests are being received... I don't know why it doesn't show any earning

Comment: And has a fillrate of 0%

Comment: i have a smart banner if that counts..

Answer (score 0):

You have a **very** low number of requests. So any data should be treated with a pinch of salt. Having a fill rate of 0% just means that there have been no ads available for your app for those 299 requests.

As you get a wider coverage you will get better fill rate.

You can also improve your fill rate by using a mediator.